# finding common genes from Gene list

Tags: python, indexing

```
 pathway=(list(set(genes.iloc[0]).intersection(genes.iloc[i+1]))),(list(set(genes.iloc1).intersection(genes.iloc[i+2]))),(list(set(genes.iloc[2]).intersection(genes.iloc[i+3]))),(list(set(genes.iloc[3]).intersection(genes.iloc[i+4])
```

Instead of writing 0,1,2 to specify indeces, Is there any way to loop through the index?

I have 90 columns in genes dataframe, so kindly help me to make it simple.

Example: genes =

[image]

I want to compare 1st row with 2,3,4,5,6,7,8. Then 2nd row with 3,4,5,6,7,8 and so on till 7th row to 8.

I have tried this code,

```
for i in range(len(keys)):
    for k in range (0,8):
        for h in range (1,9):
            pathway1=(list(set(genes.iloc[k]).intersection(genes.iloc[i+h])))
            print(pathway1)
```

But its give me only 1st row with 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 comparison not others

Comment: The first code block isn't valid Python: There are not enough closing brackets. Should that be a tuple/list? Please clarify.

Comment: Please [do not post images of data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead. Add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) that includes the expected output.

Comment: It should be list

Comment: I want these comparison for finding common genes:
1 vs 2
1 vs 3
1 vs 4
1 vs 5
1 vs 6
1 vs 7
1 vs 8
2 vs 3
2 vs 4
2 vs 5
2 vs 6
2 vs 7
2 vs 8
3 vs 4
3 vs 5
3 vs 6
3 vs 7
3 vs 8
4 vs 5
4 vs 6
4 vs 7
4 vs 8
5 vs 6
5 vs 7
5 vs 8
6 vs 7
6 vs 8
7 vs 8

Comment: Again: Provide a MRE (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/14311263)). It's not that hard.

Comment: Also: Why is your question mirrored [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74232998/for-loop-in-intersection-python), word by word?

Answer (score 2):

```py
for j in [0,1,2,3]:
    pathway=(list(set(genes.iloc[j]).intersection(genes.iloc[i+j+1])))
    #do something with pathway
```

[Take a look here for more info on loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)

Comment: for i in range(len(keys)):
    for j in [0,8]:
        pathway[j]=(list(set(genes.iloc[j]).intersection(genes.iloc[i+j+1])))
        print(pathway[j])

This code giving me only last comparison